# $ \cap_{p}\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}{C_n}\subset \cap_{p}\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{C_m} $

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and by $ w$ we shall indicate the weak topology on $X$.

Let $\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$ be the collection of all nonempty $w$-compact convex subsets of $X$.

> Let $\{C_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$. Then :
>   $$
> \cap_{p}\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}{C_n}\subset \cap_{p}\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{C_m}
> $$

with: $\overline{\text{co}}(A)=\overline{\left\{\sum _{i=1}^{n}\lambda _{i}x_{i}:n\in \mathbb {N} ,\,x_{i}\in A,\,\sum _{i=1}^{n}\lambda _{i}= 1\right\}}.$

***Proof:***

For every $p \geq 1$
$$
\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big) }\subset \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}+\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}\qquad (*)
$$
The right-hand side is closed, because $\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}$ is $w$-compact. Upon taking the intersection over all $p$ one thus obtains
$$
\cap_p\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big) }\subset \cap_p\bigg( \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}+\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}\bigg)
$$
By the following lemma:

> Let $\{C_n\}$ consist of $w$-compact and $\{D_n\}$ of $w$-closed subsets of $X$. Assume
>   that $\{C_n\}$ and $\{D_n\}$  are both nonincreasing. Then:
>   $$\cap_{n}{ (C_n + D_n)} = \cap_{n}{C_n} + \cap_{n}{D_n}.$$

this gives
$$
\cap_p\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big) }\subset \cap_p\bigg( \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}\bigg)+\cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}\bigg)\qquad (**)
$$

It is easy to check that  $\cap_p\bigg( \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}\bigg)$ is actually identical to $\text{co}\big(\{0\}\cup \frac{1}{p}C_1\big)$ (note that $\{0\}\cup \frac{1}{p}C_1$, being $w$-compact, has a convex hull that is also $w$-compact). Therefore, it follows immediately that $\cap_p\bigg( \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}\bigg)$  is equal to $\{0\}$, in view of the boundedness of $C_1$. Substitution in $(**)$ gives
$$
\cap_p\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big) }\subset \cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}\bigg)\subset \cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big)}\bigg)
$$
which leads to
$$
\cap_p\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big) }\subset \cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{n\geq 2}{C_n}\bigg)=\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{n\geq 2}{C_n}
$$
The proof is now easily completed by induction.

***My problem***:
Why we have $(*)$?

Comment: Karim KHAN [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640886/cap-p-overline-textco-cup-m-geq-p-frac1m-sum-n-1mc-n-subse/3656998?noredirect=1#comment7607101_3656998)
why holds one of inclusions near the end of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the closure of a convex set in a Banach space is convex, the right-hand side $R$ of ($*$) is convex.  Since it is also closed, to show ($*$) it  suffices to remark that $R$ contains a set  $\frac{1}{m}C_1+ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}$ for each $m\ge p$.

Comment: Why $\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}+\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}$ is closed subset ?

Comment: @kakaHae This is observed at the beginning of the proof from the question. To prove this it suffices to show that the set $C=\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\frac{1}{m}C_1}$ is weakly compact and a set $C’=\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}$ is weakly closed, because in each Hausdorff topological group (and so in each Hausdorff linear topological space, in particular, in $(X,w)$) a sum of a compact set and a closed set is closed.

Comment: By [Hahn-Banach separation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem), a closed convex subset of a Banach space is weakly closed, so both $C$ and $C’$ are weakly closed. Moreover, $C$ is contained in $\overline{\operatorname{co} (C_1\cup\{0\})}$, and a set $\operatorname{co} (C_1\cup\{0\})$ is weakly compact because it is an image of a weakly compact set $[0,1]\times (C_1\cup\{0\})\subset\Bbb R\times X$ by a continuous map $(\lambda,x)\mapsto \lambda x$ for each $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $x\in (X,w)$.

Comment: $[0,1]\times (C_1\cup \{0\})$ is weakly compact set of $\mathbb{R}\times X$?

Comment: @kakaHae I meant this set is compact in $\Bbb R\times (X,w)$. This holds because it is given that the set $C_1$ is weakly compact, so $C_1\cup \{0\}$ is weakly compact. Then $[0,1]\times (C_1\cup \{0\})$ is compact as a Cartesian product of compact sets.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Why:
$$
\cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}}\bigg)\subset \cap_p\bigg(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{m\geq p}{\big(\overline{\text{co}}\cup_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\big)}\bigg)
$$

Comment: @KarimKHAN I’ll think about your question. Meantime I [redirected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640886/cap-p-overline-textco-cup-m-geq-p-frac1m-sum-n-1mc-n-subse/3656998?noredirect=1#comment7607793_3640886) it to the asker who stated the claim.

Comment: This proof I find it in article "Two Generalizations of Komlós' theorem with Lower Closure-Type Applications" by Balder E. and Hess C. I hope that : $$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=2}^{m}{C_n}\subset \overline{\text{co}}\cup_{n=2}^{m}C_n$$ If I am not right you can correct me.